# Retrieve the contents of first three rows of a android database using a cursor

Tags: android, database, cursor

Currently in my code i'm using a cursor to retrieve the entire database 
My code is

```
public Cursor getAll() {
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id, note, amt, dueDate FROM New", null));

}
```

The function of retrieving the contents is to populate the same in a listview.

Now I want to retrieve the contents of the first three rows of the same database using cursor to display in another listview.

Need Help, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is to limit the result number to three:

```
"SELECT _id, note, amt, dueDate FROM New ORDER BY _id LIMIT 3"
```

Then you just iterate over the cursor (as usual)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already obtained a `Cursor`, in order to get the first three rows of the result, you do this:

```
Cursor cursor = getAll();
cursor.moveToFirst();
int count = 0;
while(!cursor.isAfterLast() && count < 3)
{
  // Grab your data here using cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getString(1) etc.
  // and store it an array.
  count++;
  cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

You may want to limit the query results to at most three by adding a `LIMIT 0,3` statement to your SQL. Having obtained an array of at most three elements containing your records, you can then proceed to place them in the other `ListView` you are referring to. You do this by adding them to this ListView's source array. Then call the ListView adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged` method to have it update itself.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this in two ways:

1. Create a separate select:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Table_Name LIMIT 3;
   ```
2. Select three rows from cursor:

   ```
   int n = 0;
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   while (!cur.isAfterLast() && n < 3) {
       // Use the data
       n++;
       cur.moveToNext();
   }
   cur.close();
   ```

Comment: Thanks folks. Solved the problem and understood a couple of ways to do it.